# Add web part property to all SharePoint Web Parts

Tags: web-part

Is there a way to add a web part property to every web part (SharePoint 2010), including OOTB web parts. Essentially I want to add a header color option to the appearance section of the web part tool pane. At first glance I do not think this will be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "add a property" you mean configure it? - If that is the case it should be possible.
If the answer is rather NOT, but actually "extending" the WebPart definition with a NEW property, then you could make sure your own web parts use the same base WebPart.

And not for the OOBT web parts, unless you build Control Adapters and as soon as they will load you could insert your piece of code.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: No I meant actually add it as a configurable option. So maybe under Chrome in Appearance it would have Title Color. I know I could add it to any custom web parts and of course I do need it for all of them. Ill have to take a peak at the control adapters thanks.